# Как Drop-нуть объект из окна формы наружу?

Tags: delphi, события, мышь

Как Drop-нуть объект из окна формы за пределы всех окон своей программы?   Например, на рабочий стол или ещё куда. На самом деле, "на что" именно дропнуть, на этом этапе мне не важно, зато важно "куда" - т.е. координаты мыши (глобальные) в момент отпускания кнопки. Мне нужно открывать в этом месте новое окно (с дропнутым содержимым).

Answer (score 1):

*Два года назад у меня была очень интересная группа студентов, мы сообща писали программу для обработки данных мутаций. Поскольку предполагаемая аудитория пользователей этой программы - люди, не очень подкованные в обращении с компьютером, создатели хотели упростить ввод-вывод данных: данные "забирались" с рабочего стола и отправлялись на рабочий стол. Возникла проблема - как получить координаты курсора мыши вне формы.*

В итоге было придумано несколько вариантов:

**Самый продвинутый**: установить глобальный хук посредством `SetWindowsHookEx` и написанием DLL для функции отлова отжатия кнопки мыши и возвращения координат курсора.

**Самый оригинальный**: создать прозрачную форму на весь экран, а сверху - уже рабочую со свойством AlwaysOnTop

**Самый ленивый**: когда необходимо забрать или отправить данные, включаем таймер, который каждые 50 миллисекунд сохраняет глобальные координаты курсора в переменную, а отключается, когда отжали кнопку мыши. Код:

```
var
  object_cur_pos: TPoint;

<...>
procedure DataForm.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   <...>
   if ExternalCursorOn and MouseTimer.Enabled then MouseTimer.Enabled:=false; // прекратить отслеживание координат
   <...>
end;

procedure DataForm.MouseTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetCursorPos(object_cur_pos); // считать глобальные координаты курсора
end;
```